# The "" is invalid: : spec.template.spec.volumes.userData in body is a forbidden property

Tags: kubernetes, yaml

I'm new to kubernetes and **trying to deploy VM using Kubernetes** and using this **[YAML](https://gist.github.com/rajatsingh25aug/5f522906f2606613927c5cd43d2b6c9e)**. But when I do
**`oc create -f <yaml_link_above>`**, I get an error as

***`The  "" is invalid: : spec.template.spec.volumes.userData in body is a forbidden property`***

I don't see any problem with the formatting with the YAML or whatsoever, maybe I'm missing anything?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your Dynamic Provisioning doesn't work properly. Follow these steps [dynamics-provisioning-ceph](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.5/install_config/storage_examples/ceph_rbd_dynamic_example.html) to configure Ceph RBD Dynamic Storage Class.

Then check if pvc is created properly. After all apply your VM config file.

Here are useful documentations: [hardware-configuration](https://kubevirt.io/user-guide/docs/latest/creating-virtual-machines/virtualized-hardware-configuration.html), [disk-volumes](https://kubevirt.io/user-guide/docs/latest/creating-virtual-machines/disks-and-volumes.html).

Comment: Yes thanks, my PVCs were in the pending state, I checked and found out that the storageclass name was wrong so I fixed . that and everything was up  and running! :)

Comment: Oh, gread. Can you approve and upvote, it will be useful for users with similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have an indentation error:

```
---
apiVersion: kubevirt.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualMachine
metadata:
  labels:
    kubevirt.io/vm: vm-cirros-datavolume-file
  name: vm-cirros-datavolume-file-new
spec:
  dataVolumeTemplates:
  - metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      name: cirros-dv-file
    spec:
      pvc:
        accessModes:
         - ReadWriteOnce
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 2Gi
        storageClassName: ocsinit-ceph-rbd 
      source:
        registry:
          url: docker://kubevirt/cirros-registry-disk-demo:latest
    status: {}
  running: true
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        kubevirt.io/vm: vm-cirros-datavolume-file
    spec:
      domain:
        devices:
          disks:
          - disk:
              bus: virtio
            name: datavolumedisk1
          - disk:
              bus: virtio
            name: cloudinitdisk
        machine:
          type: ""
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: 64M
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 0
      volumes:
      - dataVolume:
          name: cirros-dv-file-new
        name: datavolumedisk1
      - cloudInitNoCloud:
          userData: |    <== add two spaces to userData
            #!/bin/sh
            echo 'printed from cloud-init userdata'
        name: cloudinitdisk
```

Comment: This is the error that's popping rn ` **The  "" is invalid: spec.dataVolumeTemplate[0]: DataVolumeTemplate entry spec.dataVolumeTemplate[0] must be referenced in the VMI template's 'volumes' list** `